# What is differential instructions in PLC?

Tags: plc

I'm using Omron CP1L PLC and program with CX-programmer. I have hard time understanding what exactly is **"Differential Instructions"**, from the documentation:

> With differentiated instructions, execution results for instructions
>   are reflected in Condition Flags only when execution condition is met,
>   and results for a pre- vious rung (rather than execution results for
>   the differentiated instruction) will be reflected in Condition Flags
>   in the next cycle. You must therefore be aware of what Condition Flags
>   will do in the next cycle if execution results for differ- entiated
>   instructions to be used.

My understanding is: instruction always execute when condition is met, and of course if Condition Flags exist to get its state of ON or OFF from previous rung's instruction, instructions on the next rung would get executed. So I completely do not grasp the point of the explanation in the documentation. And see no difference between the two:

***(A) Without using differential***

[image: Without differential]

***(B) Using differential***
[image]

Comment: http://www.fatek.com/Download%20Page/English/FBe_Manual/Basic/Chapter_4.pdf

Comment: Doesn't help. No explanation. I see no difference between Differential Function and Conditional Flags - seems like the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the manual is warning you about is that, in the incorrect case, Instruction A will be executed only once after C becomes true (differentiated instruction) but the execution of Instruction B depends on the state of the condition flag from the instruction executed in A.  If A is executed only once then the condition flag is only valid for the current PLC scan.  Subsequent PLC scans with C satisfied will NOT execute differential instruction A but MAY execute differential instruction B -- IF a previous rung performs a comparison operation and sets the global condition flag TRUE.

If you understand the danger of global variables, this is basically the same thing.  Some flags in PLC logic are global flags used by certain instructions.  They remain valid only immediately after the instruction is executed and will change each time it is executed on different data.  In the incorrect case an unguarded rung is dangling with a global condition flag for an operation which is NOT guaranteed to execute.

In the Correct case the execution condition is differentiated instead of the instruction.  When C becomes true it goes to a [DIFU D].  This makes D true for the next PLC scan ONLY - D will only EVER be true for one PLC scan each time C goes from FALSE to TRUE.  This guarantees that Instruction A (which generates the Condition Flag value) is executed only once and, further, that it is guaranteed to execute every time that the condition flag exposing Instruction B is encountered.

Edit : Problematic execution flow - state of CF is RANDOM (more precisely : uncontrolled!) unless we have just performed a comparison operation.  All other comparison operations in the entire program will alter its value every time a comparison instruction executes anywhere in the program!

```
STATE          C          Instruction A       CF(=)    InstructionB

Scan #1  :    OFF             N/E            RANDOM       N/E
Scan #2  :    ON         EXECUTES > TRUE      TRUE       EXECUTES  //desired
Scan #3  :    ON              N/E            RANDOM(T)    N/E
Scan #4  :    ON              N/E            RANDOM(F)    N/E
Scan #5  :    ON              N/E            RANDOM(T)  *EXECUTES*!! //UNDESIRED
```

Here, so long as C remains ON, Instruction B will execute every time the CF switches from FALSE To TRUE due to other comparison operations in other areas of the program.  This is not desired - we only want InstructionB to execute if InstructionA has executed and has returned CF= as TRUE.

Comment: Do you mean that, without using differentials, B would not executed in the same cycle as A, but the next run? Also, does A always execute once when C becomes true for both cases? Also, "..Subsequent PLC scans with C satisfied will NOT execute differential instruction.." But ladder goes from left to right and top down, if C satisfy then power flow always lead to Instruction A. No?

Comment: Yes, but a **differential** instruction is executed ONLY ONCE when power flow FIRST turns on.  It is not executed again until power flow turns OFF and then ON again, when it is again executed ONCE and ONLY ONCE.  A differential contact, by extension, is closed once and only once when its underlying flag becomes TRUE.  It is not closed again until the underlying flag becomes FALSE and then TRUE again, etc.

Comment: But doesn't all instructions (differential or other instructions) either not execute or execute ONLY ONCE anyway in one cycle? "in the incorrect case, instruction A will be executed only once" and in the correct case "differential instruction is executed ONLY ONCE". Then my question still stands - both the incorrect and correct diagram achieve the identical function. Everything execute one and they end up having the same logic.

Comment: wait... in the incorrect case, if Instruction A is executed in the 1st cycle, does its CF reflects the instruction's result in the same cycle (1st) or the next cycle (i.e. 2nd cycle)?

Comment: The CF is updated immediately during the scan and retains its value until another comparison instruction executes anywhere else in the program.  Its state changes in the middle of the scan when the instruction executes and it remains in that state for the remaining rungs in the program or until another comparison is made.  If you make 100 comparisons in your program then the CF will switch values 100 times during the scan.

Comment: The edited answer clears out some confusion with one remaining: If I have multiple CFs reflecting results of multiple instruction, isn't each of these CF different and allocated separately in the memory or register? Or do you mean the states of ALL Condition Flags belong ONE AND ONLY ONE memory/register address that constantly changes as program run within the same cycle?

Comment: ^ for things like comparison (CMP instruction), yes, there is only one flag for each type of result (>, >=, <, <=, =, <>) and it is global.  It changes every time a CMP instruction is executed.  This is why you need to make sure that you execute the CMP when the flag is exposed and grab the result right away.

Comment: "..This makes D true for the next PLC scan ONLY..." Do you mean if [DIFU U] is executed in 1st cycle, then D is random in the 1st cycle but TRUE for the 2nd cycle? So using differential will set the boolean for the n+1 cycle instead of the same cycle? But CF is grabbed right away..it's contradictory

Comment: No, D here represents some bit in working memory, not a special flag like a CF.  This is a specific bit which is linked to the [DIFU D] instruction.  D will be closed for one full scan only on the scan following (scan+1) a change in C from FALSE to TRUE.  Here D might be something like W15.00 (work area bit, etc).  D is never random - it is only ever TRUE for the scan following a FALSE->TRUE transition in C and it is always FALSE otherwise.